# Would casting the Ventriloquism spell into a Silence field allow you to cast silently?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, spell-components, spellcasting, area-of-effect

I know [Ventriloquism](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/v/ventriloquism) is an arcane spell and [Silence](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/silence/) divine, so normally most people wouldnt be able to cast both without needing magic items or such.

But if you were to use Ventriloquism to throw your voice into a Silence field, would that work? You are still casting the spell, its just that Ventriloquism makes it seem like its coming from somewhere else.

Comment: This is a cool question. I'd also be interested in the opposite, would Ventriloquism allow you to cast if you project outside of the silent area you are currently in. But I'll wait for the answers to this first.

Comment: @linksassin That is an interesting question, you should ask it since you thought of it

Comment: The current answer actually already addresses it so it would just be a duplicate of this one. I thought that might the case.

Answer (score 5):

## Using [Ventriloquism](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/v/ventriloquism) to throw your voice into an area of [Silence](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/silence/).

[Silence](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/silence/) says:

> Upon the casting of this spell, complete silence prevails in the affected area. All sound is stopped: **Conversation is impossible, spells with verbal components cannot be cast, and no noise whatsoever issues from, enters, or passes through the area.** The spell can be cast on a point in space, but the effect is stationary unless cast on a mobile object. The spell can be centered on a creature, and the effect then radiates from the creature and moves as it moves. An unwilling creature can attempt a Will save to negate the spell and can use Spell Resistance, if any. Items in a creature’s possession or magic items that emit sound receive the benefits of saves and Spell Resistance, but unattended objects and points in space do not. Creatures in an area of a silence spell are immune to sonic or language-based attacks, spells, and effects.

To break it down into a simpler format for understanding (at least for me), silence prevents the following in it's area:

- Conversation
- Casting spells with verbal components
- Sound entering or leaving

This seems like it would make it impossible for ventriloquism to make sound come from an area of silence, but that is incorrect. [Ventriloquism](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/v/ventriloquism) states:

> You can make your voice (or any sound that you can normally make vocally) **seem to issue from someplace else**. You can speak in any language you know. With respect to such voices and sounds, anyone who hears the sound and rolls a successful save recognizes it as illusory (but still hears it).

So while your voice may seem to be coming from the area of silence, it is not actually doing so. So you would be able to make it seem like your voice is coming from an area of silence.

---

#### However, can you use ventriloquism to speak to someone in a silence field?

The answer is no. Silence prevents any sound from entering it's area of effect, which is what Ventriloquism tries to do.

Similarly, you couldn't use Ventriloquism to cast spells with a verbal component inside of an area of Silence for two reasons. One, because silence specifically forbids that, and two, because your voice is still coming from the area of silence for the purpose of the spell, ventriloquism just makes it seem like it's not.

Comment: I agree you cant speak with someone in a silence field (which wasnt in the question) it was casting in the field, which I dont believe you correctly answer. Your voice SEEMS to come from somewhere else, it doesnt actually, so you should fulfill the casting requirements and you are not actually in the field so your not unable to cast spells.

Comment: @Fering I think you're referring to the conclusion I reach in the first part, where if you're outside the area of silence, you can use ventriloquism to make it seem like it's coming from the area of silence.

Comment: I actually missed that line between the box and horizontal live above the bolded statement